# How to check date if its 12 hour format or 24 hour format in PHP?

Tags: php, contains, date-parsing

I want to check the date input and convert it to 24h format. For example the datetime is:

```
$date="2021-02-5 11:45:00 AM"
```

and after i check it with this condition:

```
 if (preg_match("/am|pm|AM|PM/", $date))
        {
            $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("$date"));
        }
```

and my output should be like this however it does not return a date format like that:

```
$date="2021-02-5 11:45:00";
```

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", is it because you get `05` rather than `5`? What's what you're asking with `d`. Format codes are documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters).

Comment: `"$date"` is equivalent to `$date`.

Comment: do you receive the same date format all the time ? The best way to deal with dates in php is to use the internal functions, such as DateTime object which allow you to createFromFormat and then format method to transform it, i can show you an example if you want in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `regex` to check if it is 24 hours or 12 hours. you can simply pass the date to `strtotime` function to get a timestamp of the date and then format the timestamp with `date` function.

```php
$date="2021-02-5 11:45:00 AM";
$date=date('Y-m-j H:i:s',strtotime($date));
echo $date;  // 2021-02-5 11:45:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting time format

```
// 24-hour time to 12-hour time 
$time_in_12_hour_format  = date("g:i a", strtotime("13:30"));

// 12-hour time to 24-hour time 
$time_in_24_hour_format  = date("H:i", strtotime("1:30 PM"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_create_from_format('Y-m-j H:i:s A', $date);
```

It will return a DateTime object, and you can get right date you want, and it will return false if date string don't match the pattern.

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2021-02-05 11:45:00.000000
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
```

```
date_create_from_format ( string $format , string $time , DateTimeZone $timezone = ? ) : DateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

With `strtotime` you have no control over the formats. To be on top of what is happening better use the feature-rich [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. First convert the string to a `DateTime` object and then format it to whatever you need.

```php
<?php
$dt = "2021-02-5 11:45:00 pm";

if (preg_match('/am$|pm$/i', $dt)) // is there an Ante meridiem/Post meridiem suffix?
{
    $dtFormat = 'Y-n-j H:i:s a';
}
else 
{
    $dtFormat = 'Y-n-j H:i:s';
}

$ts = DateTime::createFromFormat($dtFormat, $dt);
$date = $ts -> format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// echo 'Result: '. $date;
```